# Why this HelloWorld program of AngularJS is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The codes could be viewed at
http://jsfiddle.net/hh1mye5b/1/

or

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="dcApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div ng-controller="SpeciesController">
        <label><h2>{{name}}</h2></label>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var dcApp = augular.module("dcApp", [])
    dcApp.controller("SpeciesController",
            function ($scope) {
                $scope.name="Hello World"
            });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to show the `{{name}}` in a `<h2>` using angularJS, however, I found it didn't work.. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: One of the key tools in web-based development is the *web console*. If you had opened the web console, you would have found a message along the lines of `Uncaught ReferenceError: augular is not defined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've used `augular` rather than `angular`

```
var dcApp = augular.module("dcApp", [])
// here -----^
```

Comment: what a stupid mistake.. thanks!